# ¿Cómo puedo crear una excepción para que solo acepte cadenas y no números?

Tags: java

Necesito crear una excepción para mi interfaz grafica, pasa que debo pedir edad, año, nombre completo; pasa que las excepciones para no ingresar cadenas en texto las logre hacer con *NumberFormatExeption ex* pero no se como hacerlo para en la casilla donde se digita la cadena del nombre mandar un error si un caso se digita números.

¿Me ayudarían a crear un excepción para validar solo cadenas en la casilla de **txt_nombre**?

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
try {
    nombre = txt_nombre.getText();

    identificador = Integer.parseInt(txt_identificacion.getText());

    edad = Integer.parseInt(txt_edad.getText());

    ingresoMensual = Integer.parseInt(txt_mensual.getText());

    numeroMeses = Integer.parseInt(txt_meses.getText());
    montoPrestamo = Integer.parseInt(txt_prestamo.getText());
    // try{
    // }
    //catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error valor ");
    // }
    //envio de los datos a la clase Prestamo para su respectivo calculo
    rentaPagar = resultado.calculo(montoPrestamo, numeroMeses);

    if (montoPrestamo < 300000 || montoPrestamo > 15000000) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "el monto debe estar entre 300000-1500000");

    } else {

        String fecha = fechaActual(); //pasar la fecha a un nuevo string

        //JoptionPane para poder mostrar la boleta final.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su Nombre es :" + getNombre()
                + "\nSu Identificador de pedido es :" + Identificador()
                + "\nSu edad es :" + getEdad()
                + "\nSu identificacion personal es : " + getIdentificador()
                + "\nFecha :" + fecha
                + "\nSu renta a pagar es :" + getRentaPagar());

    }
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error ");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fallo no identificado " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del evento `KeyTyped`  para cada JtextField dependiendo que quieres restringir, en este caso para `txtNombre` no va aceptar digitar números.

```
  private void txtNombreKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
        char keyChar = evt.getKeyChar();
         if(Character.isDigit(keyChar)){//
             evt.consume();//no sea procesado de la manera predeterminada por la fuente que lo originó
             System.out.println("No está permitido números");             
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar una expresión regular.

Comprobando si una cadena contiene números / símbolos.

```
boolean resultado = false;  
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$");  
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("asadwwxZZ8"); 
if(matcher.find())  
    resultado = true;// Solo hay alfabetos en su cadena de entrada
else{  
    resultado = false;//su cadena contiene algún número / carácter especial,etc.
}
```

Y después un *Try-catch* personalizado:

```
try{
    if(!matcher.find()){ // si la cadena contiene numero o simbolos
        throw new Exception("No es una cadena");
    }
    //Esto no se ejecutará si ocurre una excepción
    System.out.println("ERROR");
    
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede hacer uso del método `matches()` de `String` tal que así `nombre.matches(".*\\d.*")`

Tal y como te he puesto el método matches validará que se cumpla el regex que le he pasado por párametro. Ese regex valida si contiene algún numero.

Otra opción seria partir el `String` en un `char[]` y validar carácter a carácter con el método `Character.isDigit` en un `for`.

Una vez validado si tiene dígitos puedes lanzar una excepción con `throw new Exception();`

Si quieres crearte tu propia excepción basta con crear una clase que herede de la clase `Exception` y se lanza de la misma manera que te he puesto mas arriba con `throw new CustomException();`

Comment: ok muchas gracias